# how to retrieve all value from table data from database in asp.net & display in string/label

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
con.Open();
string query = "select Calf_ID,Plant,date1,Event from Holiday_Master ";
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    Label1.Text = dr["Calf_ID"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = dr["Plant"].ToString();
    Label3.Text = dr["date1"].ToString();
    Label4.Text = dr["Event"].ToString();
}

con.Close();
```

I am using this code but it retrieves only one row from table I want all data from Table.

Comment: How will you fit many rows in only one label?

Comment: It will overwrite the values and you will get the last row only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try a grid view

```
con.Open();
string query = "select Calf_ID,Plant,date1,Event from Holiday_Master ";
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   GridView1.DataSource = dr;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}

con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
con.Open();
string query = "select Calf_ID,Plant,date1,Event from Holiday_Master ";
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{

    Label1.Text += dr["Calf_ID"].ToString();
    Label2.Text += dr["Plant"].ToString();
    Label3.Text += dr["date1"].ToString();
    Label4.Text += dr["Event"].ToString();
}

con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
} 


//ADO.NET CODES

    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;


    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["DBCS"].ConnectionStrings;
    using(SqlConnection con = ne SqlConnection(cs))
    {
       List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Employee",con);
       cmd.commandType = CommandType.Text;
       con.Open();
       SqlReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       while(rdr.Read())
       {
          Employee emp = new Employee();
          emp.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmployeeId"]);
          emp.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();

          employee.Add(emp);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some comments as to what your code does and how it helps to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

On MVC5 you can use:

```
List<EntityName> varName = db.EntityName.ToList(); //This selects all rows from the table
```

Then you can iterate your list to display the info string/label